# How to find a minimum in a List using only reduce?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to use only `reduce` to find a minimum in a `List<Integer>`. Here's what first came into my head:

```
List<Integer> lst;
//init
//assuming it's not empty
lst.stream().reduce(lst.get(0), (x, y) -> x.compareTo(y) <= 0  ? x : y);
```

But in ***[the contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)*** of that method said:

> The `identity` value must be an identity for the accumulator function.
>   This means that for all t, `accumulator.apply(identity, t)` is equal to
>   `t`. The accumulator function must be an associative function.

So, the only possible `identity` value preserving the contract for accumulator `(x, y) -> x.compareTo(y) <= 0  ? x : y` is the maximum one. Therefore we have some kind of chicken-egg problem.

How to solve it preserving all contracts?

Comment: Use `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Or the [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) that returns an `Optional`.

Comment: Just curious, whats wrong with 
lst.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).min();

Comment: @TriCore Nothing, I'm just trying to understand the reduction.

Comment: I'm very curious if anyone can show a scenario where not following the contract would actually cause a bug.

Comment: The MAX_VALUE identity works fine if your stream will never be empty after all filters are applied, but the 2-param reduce will evaluate to MAX_VALUE if it ever does happen.  Better to use the 1-param reduce to avoid that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  Everything else will be less than or equal to that, so it satisfies the contract that `min(identity, t) == t` for all `t`.

Upon looking into it further, I don't think you need the identity.  There is a `reduce` that just takes the function as the argument, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-.  This would return `Optional<Integer>` instead of `Integer`.  The reason, I believe, is that the method has to handle the case where there are no elements in the stream.  In that case, the `Optional<Integer>` version would return an empty value; while the version that needs an `identity` and returns an `Integer` would return the identity value (similarly to how in mathematics if you add a set of numbers and it's empty, you should get 0, and if you multiply a set of numbers and it's empty, you should get 1).  So if you know your list is nonempty, you should actually be able to write

```
lst.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x.compareTo(y) <= 0  ? x : y).get();
```

Comment: Thank you. But can't you also explain the reason they don't provide a method like `reduce(T anyObjectNotNecessaryIdentity, BinaryOperator<T>)`?

Comment: @user3663882 The min function is special in that any input element works as the first arg of reduce(). If you were doing summation, then the binary operator would be `+`, whose identity of course is zero. If you were to use any other value as the first arg, you'd get the wrong answer.

Comment: @user3663882: the thing you ask for exists. Just use `reduce(BinaryOperator<T> reductionFunction) .orElse(T anyObjectNotNecessaryIdentity)`

Comment: Though, instead of `.reduce((x, y) -> x.compareTo(y) <= 0  ? x : y)` you can simply use `.min(Comparator.naturalOrder())`

Comment: @Holger true, but the OP did say that they posted the question because they wanted to understand `reduce`.

Answer (score 6):

You could avoid/defer the issue by using the single argument `reduce(...)` method on `Stream` like so:

```
lst.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x.compareTo(y) <= 0  ? x : y);
```

This will return an `Optional<Integer>`, which you will need to deal with, maybe something like this:

```
lst.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x.compareTo(y) <= 0  ? x : y).ifPresent(this::processValue);
```

But you could also use `Math.min(...)` to achieve the same outcome more succinctly:

```
lst.stream().reduce(Math::min)
```

Also returning an `Optional<Integer>`, but involving boxing/unboxing for comparisons.

You could unbox before running through `Math.min(...)` which might be slightly more efficient:

```
lst.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).reduce(Math::min);
```

This returns an `OptionalInt` which can be handled in similar ways to `Optional<Integer>` without the unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for getting min

```
int min = lst.stream().reduce(Integer::min).get();
```

For getting max

```
int min = lst.stream().reduce(Integer::max).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem with only reduce :

```
List<Integer> lst;
//init
//assuming it's not empty
int min = lst.get(0);
min = lst.stream().reduce(min, (x, y) -> x.compareTo(y) <= 0  ? x : y);
System.out.println(min);
```

It does not litterally respect the contract because the min may not be the first element, but solves the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... but it's not reliable isn't?

Comment: Why isn't it ? As you initialize min with the first element, you're guaranteed that it cannot be inferior to the minimum of the list.

Comment: Well, be honest. I don't know :). Refusing to follow contracts might be prone to very subtle bugs...